# Using JSON/Web Service to call media such as video stored on a server through MySQL database in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, mysql, json, video, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to work on a Windows Phone 8 project where videos are played in an augmented reality type view using SLARToolkit, I've managed to get the video to function how I want it to by directly embedding it into the code using MediaElement source="..." as is standard.

As this is for my final year university project, I was told that it is proper to have media stored on a database which is then called into the program via what I would assume is streaming.

I've done some reading/googling around this, and I've found that the "proper" way to setup a media based MySQL call is to not directly store the video into the MySQL Database, rather use the database to create a reference and store the video on a server then use the web service to retrieve the video from the server into the application, So I have a few questions in regards to this:

1. Firstly, is this actually the correct way? And what is the best framework/web service to use for this if so? Would it be REST, JSON etc.? I've found tutorials like [this](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494/) and [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application/) but they all describe retrieving text based lists, nothing on media.
2. How would I actually go about doing this, would I have to reference the SQL reference as a new URI or? Any suggestions or pointers as to how the code would work would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About 1, yes, is one way to do it. You can store the video using an UUID, instead of its original name, to avoid conflicts between two different videos with the same name. Then, in the DB you store this UID. Finally, when the user requests the video list, you can either send it the UUID along with the rest of the video data, and compose the final video URL in the client side (phone) or, maybe better, compose the URL in the server side and return it to the client.

This URLs, whether is being composed in the client or in the server, will be used to retrieve the video and stream it. Notice that in the streaming part REST, JSON or whatever you use to retrieve video list is no longer used. Also, this server URL will reference to a (possibly) static resource in the server, which is the video. That means, if you open this URL in a browser, you'll be accessing the video.

About 2, I do not fully understand your question, but I think it may be answered in the answer to 1.

Comment: Hi Xavier, Thanks for your reply, the UID sounds easy enough, I'd basically just create a table in MySQL and set the UID as the primary key, meaning that each video is now associated with a UID being it's primary key, is that correct?

The video is shown through the camera via an augmented reality view, using Matrix3D projection, the video only pops up on screen when the user points the camera over a special marker.

So when you say compose, what do you mean? How would I compose a video on my localhost server for example? And then reference this in XAML/C# of my project?

Comment: And by question two, I meant, would I do for example <MediaElement Source ="URL From Server" or would I have to reference it to it's SQL UID somehow? and if so, how? How would you send the UID along with the video data as you stated?

Comment: Could it also be quite possibly to do with something based around IsolatedStorage? I feel like I'm close to a solution, but I just can't put my finger on it! I hope you and anybody else can help.

Comment: UUID may be your primary key, but it's not a must, it can be a simple field. The important fact is that you have to relate this UUID to the video file in the disk. The easiest way is: rename the file to the UUID. For example, rename it to 1234-5678-ABCD.mp4. Then make sure each video file is accessible as a static resource in your web server. For example, as http://myserver.com/videos/1234-5678-ABCD.mp4 That will be your URL. In the server, you only have to compose this UUID with the rest of the URL and send it back to the client. This will be the source for your MediaElement.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense, Thank you Xavier I will try and get an actual online server and host the video as a static resource, just one more question, where will the actual Database file be stored in relation to this solution? And what influence and function will it have in the application other than just providing a UUID, it seems at the moment, the database is just lying there on my computer with a UUID in it with no real function related to the video displaying within the app, is this how it is meant to work?

Comment: The database must be a way to add information to your videos and be able to query for this information to locate and filter the videos. For example, add a title to the video, an author or the date of creation. Then, for example, you can query for all the videos from author logikurl, and created two days ago. If you only need to access videos by its UUID, then of course it makes little sense, but I guess the former case will be much more useful than the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance Xavier you have done me a massive favour, I have applied everything you have said, the way my app functions I don't actually need any user interaction with the Database, it's mainly for back-end management that contains information on the objects I have stored in it. I now have successfully streaming media from the web server and have begun to setup a database in PHPMyAdmin, I have a search page that may need to pull queries from the PHPMyAdmin database, and allow users to click on results that hyperlink to webpages with information, any ideas on this?